# Xml with two attributes in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I want to make xml element like this:

```
<ElementName Type="FirstAttribute" Name="SecondAttribute">Value</Atrybut>
```

Now I'm doing this in this way:

```
XmlNode xmlAtrybutNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ElementName ");

_xmlAttr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Type");
_xmlAttr.Value = "FirstAttribute";
xmlAtrybutNode.Attributes.Append(_xmlAttr);

_xmlAttr = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("Name");
_xmlAttr.Value = "SecondAttribute";
xmlAtrybutNode.Attributes.Append(_xmlAttr);


xmlAtrybutNode.InnerText = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Value) 
    ? SetTextLength(Name, ValueLength) 
    : string.Empty;
```

Value is input variable in method.
Is there possibility to make this in another way?
More efficiently? 
Can I use xmlWriter? Now i'm using xmlDocument.

Comment: if you are trying to serialize objects from your app take a look at `XmlSerializer`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Comment: What you are trying to generate looks pretty broken XML.

Comment: Why pretty broken? I'm doing this according to specification. I have sample xml output and I have to produce that xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about tweaking your existing code:

```
XmlElement el = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ElementName");
el.SetAttribute("Type", "FirstAttribute");
el.SetAttribute("Name", "SecondAttribute");
el.InnerText = ...;
```

Additional thoughts:

- XElement
- XmlSerializer (from a class instance)

Answer (score 6):

You can use Linq to XML.

Basically

```
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        doc.Add(
            new XElement("ElementName", "Value",
                new XAttribute("Type", "FirstAttribute"),
                new XAttribute("Name", "SecondAttribute")));
```

will give this xml document

```
<ElementName Type="FirstAttribute" Name="SecondAttribute">Value</ElementName>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you’re on .NET 3.5 (or later), you could use LINQ to XML. Make sure that the `System.Xml.Linq` assembly is referenced, and that you have a `using` directive for its eponymous namespace.

```
XDocument document = new XDocument(
    new XElement("ElementName",
        new XAttribute("Type", "FirstAttribute"),
        new XAttribute("Name", "SecondAttribute"),
        value));
```

If you subsequently want to write the `XDocument` to a target, you can use its `Save` method. For debugging, it’s useful to call its `ToString` method, which returns its XML representation as a `string`.

**Edit**: Replying to comment:

If you need to convert the `XDocument` created above into an `XmlDocument` instance, you may use code similar to the following:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
using (XmlReader xmlReader = document.CreateReader())
    xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
```

Comment: Can i add this document as appendChild to xmlDocument?

Answer (score 3):

What about using LINQ to XML as in this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24376/LINQ-to-XML). That can be very elegant - it can all be done on one line.

```
 XDocument doc = new XDocument(
      new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
      new XElement("element",
            new XAttribute("attribute1", "val1"),
            new XAttribute("attribute2", "val2"),
       )
);
```